# Can I put a widget inside a folder?

Tags: app-widgets, home-screen-folders

I have a number of widgets that I really like, but my Droid takes an awful long time to draw the home screen, even using the Zeam launcher replacement.

Can I use folders on my home screen to hold widgets (and keep them handy) and will that improve my performance any?

Comment: I think it would only work if the "folder" was a widget that you could put other widgets inside of?

Comment: I can also recommend reducing the number of homescreens you use.  I went from 7 screens to 4 with Launcher Pro and noticed a significant performance boost.

Comment: I'm already limiting Zeam to 3 screens. I suppose if put to it I could reduce it to two.

Comment: Provided that the issue is relevant to you or somebody else and ready for a small compromise, one can launch a widget from a shortcut and we all know a shortcut can always be dragged into a folder, that's what the latter is meant for. In such case, see my answer(s) for [How do I launch a widget from a shortcut on Home screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/120929)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much experimenting, it is apparent that you *cannot* put a widget inside a folder. Folders will only hold shortcuts.

I have a stock Motorola Droid with Android 2.2.1. Admittedly, there may be a ROM out there that lets this happen, and perhaps even a customized version from some carrier/manufacturer that allows it. But without *significant* modification, this just can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

There is a widget that allows you to combine widgets into a 1x1 square, called [WidgetFolder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jangsp.widgetfolder). Unfortunately, it's not as sleek as even the standard folders, as clicking on it doesn't slide out a pop-up with the contained widgets (or files, apps, contacts etc), but opens up a separate screen where you can open, arrange and add widgets (or other folder items). Opening up that screen takes a good one or two seconds, which can become quite frustrating in the long run. It also crashes to force close every now and then, especially when you're arranging or deleting icons from it. But so far it's the only one I've found. Sadly, it's definitely not good enough for me to stop looking.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a late answer, but [Lightning Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.pierrox.lightning_launcher&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5ldC5waWVycm94LmxpZ2h0bmluZ19sYXVuY2hlciJd) is free, and allows you to put any widget inside a folder. You can even put more than one widget in a single folder if you like.

The downside to this launcher is that when you restart your phone, the widgets don't reload, but it could just be my phone.

Answer (score 1):

[Yandex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yandex.launcher&hl=en) launcher.It's free and I'm using it. It have some pretty cool features and nice clean looking. Its fast and can put widgets inside folders.

this is the play store link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yandex.launcher&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Almost 6 years since the question was asked, but posting it here since I myself had been here on this page looking for a way to put widgets in folders, about 2 years back.

Frustrated by the lack of a proper solution for this, I set out implementing my own launcher app.

After about 1.5 years of development (Everyday after my dayjob), today we have released 
Launcher++(Currently in Beta). Lpp can support full sized, resizable widgets in folders. Get more details here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/118333464355905775192

Comment: Plus is no longer active so your link is broken. Are you still developing this?