# Automating a widget launch

Tags: app-widgets, automation

I'd like an ability to automate launching a widget. Specifically, what I'd like to do is link the Ustream's "Broadcast Now" widget into an automation app like Tasker or Automate (preferably the latter).

I've looked around and a lot of things (like the AutoShortcut app for Tasker) claim to be able to do this, but I've had no luck as yet.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Popup Widget 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.popupWidget) can help. See my answer for [How do I launch a widget from a shortcut on Home screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120930) for its *know-how*.

Once you're done adding your widget in that app, in your automation app, there should be an option for you to launch a shortcut. Choose Popup Widget 2 shortcut → your widget.

You can also use [Short Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mibi.shortcutlauncher) app to treat the Popup Widget Shortcut 2 as an app which may help in automation.