# Swipe from the side to activate a widget overlay?

Tags: launcher, app-widgets

Have looked in various places, googled, looked on the play store, etc., but so far I've been unable to find an app or other way to do what I'm looking for, which I'll describe here:

I've been using various apps over the years that let me swipe from the side of my screen to overlay a series of shortcut icons to different apps.  Currently I use Smart Task Launcher.  However, I've recently started using Bubble Cloud Launcher for my Androidwear watch, and it also has the ability to create a homescreen widget that provides an easier/more dynamic way to set up icons.  But Smart Task Launcher doesn't allow for launching of widgets via a swipe.  Well, it's supposed to, but an error is produced when you try to set it up.  Does anyone know of an way to do this - swipe from the side of the screen and a widget of your choosing gets displayed as an overlayed "screen" on top of whatever you are currently on, whether an app or launcher screen?

Comment: Did you contact the developer of the Smart Task Launcher and present them with the issue? That would be a starting point for correcting it. BTW & FYI posting questions about app requests is against site policies. Reword the title so it doesn't get flagged,  also change towards the end "...know of an APP" to "...know a WAY". Id still contact the developer though.

Comment: See my answer for the app and its usage: [How do I launch a widget from a shortcut on Home screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/122988)

Comment: @HasH_BrowN I haven't contacted the dev about that, but I recall trying to contacting him a while ago about something else and not getting a response.  The app is rarely updated.  But yes, been thinking I should try that route as well...  Thanks for the other tips - I've made those changes. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer of Bubble Cloud Widgets. I tried, and it is fully compatible with Smart Task Launcher, but you have to invoke the special "Widget Measure Mode", since STL doesn't report the widget size correctly.

Here, I shot a video for you:

- https://youtu.be/UYsoU-xwqkI

This is my blog entry on this subject:

- https://plus.google.com/111815032990260235809/posts/1WXHmh3V9bX

Comment: Nice to see a developer (and its your app, :) very cool) helping/answering on an issue, especially one that helps with compatability.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting here and on XDA-Developers!  I'll definitely be looking through this video to understand a bit more how to set up a Bubble Cloud Widget.  However, unfortunately it doesn't get me exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm limited to how much I can write here so I'll write more on the thread on XDA.  Just suffice it to say here that the main way I've learned here (thanks to @Firelord above) is via Smart Task Launcher and yet another app - Popup Widget 2 in order to launch a Bubble Cloud Widget from within Smart Task Launcher...

Answer (score 0):

Hey here's an alternative if you are still interested:

You can use tasker scenes :) if you create a scen that fills the screen from top to bottom and just about 40-60px (i use an S6 and 40px is best for me), and position it to the right/left. Then u can set an task when you stroke the scene the way you want (i have mine on the right and use stroke 40px to the left), and from there choose a task which can open up any widger you would like to :) mine is working perfectly!